# Calculate : f(n) = 1560878×log2(n) in python for the value of n. Here Total operations performed = 987*3600

Tags: python, function

I tried to find the value of n using the below code, but it returns None. Where am I going wrong?

```
from math import log2


def f(n):
    
    y = 3600*987
    a = int(1560878*log2(n))
    for i in range(a):
        if n==1:
            n = y/a
            
            return(n)
        else:
            print(x)  

print(f(1))
```

Comment: What you want to do is unclear, is 987*3600 the input of your function or do you want to find n so that f(n) equals 987*3600?

Comment: Did you mean to have `return x` instead of `print(x)`?

Answer (score 1):

If you pass `1` as argument `a` becomes 0 so you for loop doesn't run

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring because `a` evaluates to 0, so `for i in range(a):` does not get executed, causing the function to not return anything.

logbase2(1) = 0, which is why `a` evaluates to 0.